# Sorting Matrix by row sum

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I've been looking for a way to solve this problem. I'm new to programming and was hoping someone could walk me through the thought process to solve this.

Write a program in Python that sorts all teh vertices in V = {1,...,n} according to the decreasing order of their degrees in a stable manner, for random input graph G ={V,E}.

Let V = {1,2,3,4,5} and

[image: matrix to solve for]
As a result, the output is given by B = {4,2,3,5,1}.

Comment: Is this homework/exam?

Comment: This is an old exam question I'm trying to understand. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]

matrix.sort(key=sum, reverse=True)
print(matrix)
```

**Update:**
This is in your expected output form:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
count_ones = [(i + 1, item.count(1)) for i, item in enumerate(matrix)]
count_ones.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
result = [i[0] for i in count_ones]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the issue, I have updated  my answer.

Comment: I'm looking for the original indexes to been my output so {4,2,3,5,1}. How would I not lose this when matrix.sort() is call? @TaohidalIslam

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this works